# Menu bar in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

I want to add a menu bar with drop down list in the web page so that the user can select the desired font size,font style and font color for the text they need to write in the page for further post.How to do this?

Can you guys please help me .....

Comment: Can anyone help me in a little datailed way...plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to enable a user to add rich text (much like you can in stack overflow when posting a question).  If so, the most common solutions are [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).